Sign a data using a certificate in pfx
I have a pfx file of my electronic digital signature, located in assets. I need to sign random data in base64 using this certificate and get a signed string in base64 at the output. I am developing the application on flutter windows. I tried to find libraries, but they are only for flutter android. This is my first experience working with a pfx file via dart. Please, the simplest example will solve my problem.
I tried to use ffi with c++, but the task is to write an application in pure dart without using ffi.

What do you want to sign? Executable/libraries, pdf files, or what else? The signature format depends on the file you want to sign (unless you want to create a detached signature in a separate file like gpg does).

I want to sign String in base64 which I will receive in response to a post request. For example, String s = "AABRJFKSCJ258GS"

And the signed strings will be verified by your own application? What signature format do you want to use, what type of signature key do you have (RSA, ECDSA)?

The signed string will be sent in the next post request and will be verified on the third-party server side. I have only Enhanced Qualified Digital Signature in *.pfx  (PKSC #12) and password for it. Unfortunately, I don't know what encryption method is used

Any you want to integrate that signature into an application? Be aware that anybody who has the application can extract the private key and misuse it to sign everything else. Therefore please never ever integrate an Enhanced Qualified Digital Signature into an application! Doing so may even violate the contract you signed for getting the cert, thus if you do so the cert may be revoked.

In the productive version of the application, the signature will not be inside the application, but on external secure storage. Can you help with the issue described in our correspondence with you?
